Key driver analysis in R - different packages produce slightly different results: Is this to be expected?
I am doing a key driver analysis with customer experience data. I have run the analysis with three different packages in R: rwa, relaimpo::calc.relimp and iopsych::relWt.
Each method produces slightly different values for the relative importance of each covariate. The differences are for covariates with similar importance weights in the middle of the ranking (most important and least important are consistent for all packages) - is this to be expected? I want to use the most computationally efficient package/function - is that a reasonable criteria for picking which option to go with?


is this to be expected?

I would say yes. Form a quick look, relWT implements Johnson's (2000) relative weight computation. calc.relimp implements various metric, but I don't see a reference to Johnson's (disclaimer: I'm just skimming the documentation and I'm not familiar with these methods).
Which one to choose: Since you say that results are only slightly different, I would go for the package that appears to be most popular, supported, and better documented. If there is no clear winner there (or in addition to the above), another criterion could be to choose the method that you can understand better. Unless you really have a bottleneck there, I wouldn't give much weight to computational efficiency.
